# Thesis class file, signing page not showing up

Tags: errors, thesis

http://grad.ucalgary.ca/current/thesis/latex-template

For some reason the signing page (under  Substitute  List of Examiners) doesn't show up when you compile.

The class file looks like this. I'm not sure how I could modify it to make the sign page show up when I compile the thesis.

```
\documentclass{ucalgthes1}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\fancyhead{}
%\fancyfoot{}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
%Define other usepackages here
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Title of Thesis \\ \bigskip Second ThesisTitle Line }
%
%            Insert the correct information between the {}
%
\author{Student's name}
\thesisyear{year}
\thesis{thesis}    % the word dissertation can be inserted between {}
\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Title of Thesis}
\monthname{monthname}
\dept{NAME OF DEPARTMENT}
\degree{NAME OF DEGREE IN FULL}
%
%                    End of supplied information
%
\begin{document}
\makethesistitle
\pagenumbering{roman}     % resets page counter to one
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\chapter*{UNIVERSITY OF CALGARY \\ FACULTY OF GRADUATE STUDIES}
%\thispagestyle{empty}
%The undersigned certify that they have read, and recommend
%to the Faculty of Graduate Studies for acceptance, a \Thesis\ entitled
%``\thesistitle'' submitted by \Author    %in partial fulfillment of the requirements for the degree of
%\Degree.\\

%
%                 Substitute  List of Examiners
%
%\begin{signing}{Department of Academic Computing}
%\signline
%Chairman, Dr.~John D.~Doe \\
%Department of Academic Computing \\
%Services  \\
%\signline
%Chairman, Dr.~John D.~Doe \\
%Department of Academic Computing \\
%Services  \\
%\signline
%Chairman, Dr.~John D.~Doe \\
%Department of Academic Computing \\
%Services  \\
%\signline
%Chairman, Dr.~John D.~Doe \\
%Department of Academic Computing \\
%Services  \\
%\newsigncolumn         use this command to start a new column if necessary
%\newsigncolumn
%\signline
%Chairman, Dr.~John D.~Doe \\
%Department of Academic Computing \\
%Services  \\
%\signline
%Dr.~Jane Smith \\
%Department of Academic Computing  \\

%\signline
%Dr.~A.~B.~Brown \\
%Department of Academic Computing  \\
%\end{signing}
%
\newpage
\phantomsection
\altchapter{\bf{Abstract}}
Paragraph 1

Paragraph 2

Paragragh 3
\newpage
\phantomsection
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the part you're talking about is commented out. Remove the `%` from each line you want to use.